# Why does this table cause "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item?

Tags: tables, errors, tabularray

```
\begin{table} [htbp]
\label{tab:test}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l]X[l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries},
    row{even}={bg=gray!10},
}
    \toprule
    \scriptsize{\\$\mathbf{100\%}$} & {} & {\\\scriptsize{best}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\off}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\1}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\off}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\off}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\1}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\1}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\1}} & {\scriptsize{test\\=\\1}}\\
    \midrule
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    \midrule
    \scriptsize{\\$\mathbf{90\%}$} & & & & & & & & & &\\
    {} & {\scriptsize{L1 Position}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{L1 Size}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{L1 Rotation}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{Class}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{1}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{test}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You need `{\scriptsize test}` not `\scriptsize{test}`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: `\scriptsize` is not a command with argument, but a switch. So `\scriptsize{…}` does not make sense, but should always be at least `{\scriptsize …}` (and sometimes even `\par{\scriptsize …\par}`.

This example would work without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} [htbp]
\label{tab:test}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l]X[l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries},
    row{even}={bg=gray!10},
}
    \toprule
    {\scriptsize\\$\mathbf{100\%}$} & {} & {\\\scriptsize best} & {\scriptsize
      test\\=\\off} & {\scriptsize test\\=\\1} & {\scriptsize test\\=\\off} &
    {\scriptsize test\\=\\off} & {\scriptsize test\\=\\1} & {\scriptsize
      test\\=\\1} & {\scriptsize test\\=\\1} & {\scriptsize test\\=\\1}\\
    \midrule
    {} & {\scriptsize test} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize test} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize test} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize test} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize{test}} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    \midrule
    {\scriptsize \\$\mathbf{90\%}$} & & & & & & & & & &\\
    {} & {\scriptsize L1 Position } & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize L1 Size} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize L1 Rotation } & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize Class} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {} & {\scriptsize 1} & {1} & {2} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But IMHO the braces of several of the `{1}` etc. can (and maybe should) also be removed. And you should move the `\scriptsize` also to `row{1}={\font=\bfseries\scriptsize}` instead of using it at every cell of the row. You should do similar for second column.

Note: Please always show a minimal working example instead of only a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

- It seems that your table is generated by some on-line table generator which is not "aware" or have capability to generate table code on the way as expected when is used `tabularray` package, hence table code is full of clutter of wrong written instruction `{\scriptsize{test\\=\\off}}` which eventually be `{\scriptsize test\\=\\off}`.
- In `tblr` table you can simple to prescribe font size and face for whole columns and rows, for example with `row{1} = {font=\scriptsize}` and than drop all of their instances in the first row. Similar can be done in the second column.
- Other off-topic suggestion how to simplify code and improve table looks are:

  - For writing of percentage I suggest to use `siunitx` package - it gives its better formatting.
  - It is entirely clear what is content in the first two rows, it may happened that I misinterpreted it.
  - After suggested redesign of table there is no need to use `\scriptsize` fonts in the second column.
  - Smaller font size (\small) can be used only in the first two rows due used boldface fonts. Due to this changes table is typographical unified and hence it has much better looks.
  - The changes of font sizes in the first column and the first two rows can be done in the table preamble.

An example of MWE, which consider aforementioned, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}    \bfseries} % for bold of siunitx quantities

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [htbp]
    \label{tab:test}
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight} 
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[r, preto=\B,font=\small]  % `\B is trigger for the boldface font in siunitx 
                        Q[l] 
                        *{9}{X[c]} },
             cell{1}{3} = {c=9}{c,font=\small\bfseries},
             row{2}     = {font=\small\bfseries},
             row{even}  = {bg=gray!10}, 
            }
    \toprule
    &               &   test
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule{3-11}
\B \qty{100}{\%}
    &       test    & test  
                        &   off
                            & 1 &   off
                                    &   off
                                        & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \midrule
    & text          & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & text          & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & text          & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & text          & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & text          & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \midrule
\qty{90}{\%}
    &               &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & L1 Position   & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & L1 Size       & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & L1 Rotation   & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & Class         & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1             & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{test}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
However, I assume, that the following table design, which differ from  above only in the first three table rows:

```
    \toprule
    &               &   test
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule{3-11}
    &       test    & test  
                        &   off
                            & 1 &   off
                                    &   off
                                        & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \midrule
\B \qty{100}{\%}
    &               &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
```

is more sensible:

[image]